# Export R package documentation to a web page

Tags: r, package

I have created an R package following [Hadley Wickham's instruction on how to build and document packages with Roxygen](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/). Now I would like to export the function help pages and vignettes to a bunch of html files so that it can also be read and linked-to on a website.

When I look into my library for the installed package there is an html folder but it only contains an `00Index.html` page. Is there an easy way to export the rest (function help pages and vignettes) of my package documentation?

Comment: What format is the vignette expected to be rendered to for inclusion in the package?

Comment: The vignette would be preferably in pdf format as plots take slightly less space but both are good. I know how to export vignettes to both pdf and html formats. My question is more about exporting the function documentation to html files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Hadley Wickham's in-development (i.e not on CRAN) package [**staticdocs**](https://github.com/hadley/staticdocs).

Alternatively, if you have the rendered Rd files, you could convert each to HTML using the utility function `Rd2HTML` from the **tools** package that ships with R. Read more about it using `?tools::Rd2HTML`

Comment: Thanks the instruction works to export my function documentation of `tradeflows::addregion` to an html file, I can use `Rd2HTML(Rd = "man/addregion.Rd", out = "/tmp/addregion.html", package = "tradeflows")` but there is no link to the package at the bottom of the generated file. Is there a way to make this a link. I'll check the staticdocs package.

Comment: Using the function name `Rd2HTML` as a search keyword, I found [a function created by Yihui Xie](http://yihui.name/en/2012/10/build-static-html-help/) which generates my static documentation, with links. As one comments specifies, changing the working directory to `system.file('html', package = "my_package_name")` helps generating the static html files in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

A slight modification of [Yihui Xie's function to Build Static HTML Help Pages for R Packages](http://yihui.name/en/2012/10/build-static-html-help/), so that it creates static pages in the package's html directory.

```
static_help = function(pkg, links = tools::findHTMLlinks()) {
    wd <- getwd()
    helpdir <- system.file('html', package = "tradeflows")
    setwd(helpdir)   
    message("Generated help files will be placed in ", helpdir)
    pkgRdDB = tools:::fetchRdDB(file.path(find.package(pkg), 
                                          'help', pkg))
    force(links); topics = names(pkgRdDB)
    for (p in topics) {
        tools::Rd2HTML(pkgRdDB[[p]], 
                       paste(p, 'html', sep = '.'),
                       package = pkg, 
                       Links = links, 
                       no_links = is.null(links))
    }
    setwd(wd) # Get back to the current working directory
}
```

To use it for your package in development:

```
static_help("my_package_name")
```

You will need to re-run this function each time you build the package.